# The Type Argument cannot be inferred on my two new models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using entity code first to attach to a database that currently exists and then I need to add 2 new tables. I have been having trouble with the foreign keys (tried a few different ways to fix the problem and even asked on here but to no avail), so what I am trying is to manually add the two new tables in the database and then use entity to connect to these new tables as well as the old. Unfortunately, I am getting an error in my datacontext for the two new models.

```
public class DataContext : DbContext, IDataContext
    {
        static DataContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(null);
        }

        public DataContext()
            : base("OPSPROD")
        {
        }


        /// 
        public DbSet<OpsUser> OpsUsers { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Package> Packages { get; set; }

        public DbSet<PTEInteractiveCourse> PTEInteractiveCourses { get; set; }

        public DbSet<PTETrackingClass> PTETrackingClasses { get; set; }

        public DbSet<STCIProductInteractiveInfo> STCIProductInteractiveInfos { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //modelBuilder.Entity<STCIProductInteractiveInfo>()
            //    .HasRequired(e => e.ModifyUser)
            //    .WithMany()
            //    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PackageMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PTEInteractiveCourse());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PTETrackingClass());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new STCIProductInteractiveInfoMap());

            // Add Primary key for STCIProductInteractiveInfo
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<STCIProductInteractiveInfo>().HasKey(x => new { x.STCIProductInteractiveInfoID });
        }
    }

}
```

On these two lines:

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PTEInteractiveCourse());
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PTETrackingClass());
```

I am getting this error:

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConfigurationRegistrar.Add(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ComplexTypeConfiguration)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

Here is one of the models:

```
namespace PTEManager.Domain
{
    public class PTEInteractiveCourse
    {

        public Guid PTEInteractiveCourseId { get; set; }

        public DateTime ModifyDate { get; set; }

        public int ModifyUserId { get; set; }

        public virtual OpsUser ModifyUser { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Package")]
        [ForeignKey("package_nme")]
        public int PackageId { get; set; }

        public virtual Package package_nme { get; set; }

        public int Status { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "STCI Course Name")]
        [ForeignKey("STCICourseName")]
        public Guid STCIProductInteractiveInfoID { get; set; }

        public virtual STCIProductInteractiveInfo STCICourseName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and where I map it to the table:

```
namespace PTEManager.Domain.Mapping
{
    public class PTEInteractiveCourseMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<PTEInteractiveCourse>
    {
        public PTEInteractiveCourseMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.PTEInteractiveCourseId);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.ModifyDate)
                .IsRequired();

            this.Property(t => t.ModifyUserId)
                .IsRequired();

            this.Property(t => t.PackageId)
                .IsRequired();

            this.Property(t => t.Status)
                .IsRequired();

            this.Property(t => t.STCIProductInteractiveInfoID)
                .IsRequired();

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("PTEInteractiveCourse");
            this.Property(t => t.ModifyDate).HasColumnName("ModifyDate");
            this.Property(t => t.ModifyUserId).HasColumnName("ModifyUserId");
            this.Property(t => t.PackageId).HasColumnName("PackageId");
            this.Property(t => t.Status).HasColumnName("Status");
            this.Property(t => t.STCIProductInteractiveInfoID).HasColumnName("STCIProductInteractiveInfoID");

        }
    }
}
```

This same code is working for the OpsUser, Package, and STCIProductInteractiveInfo models.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typos in your config:

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PTEInteractiveCourse());
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PTETrackingClass());
```

should be:

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PTEInteractiveCourseMap());
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PTETrackingClassMap());
```